# Android camera HAL implementation

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

Is there any skeleton code for writing  the camera HAL for android gingerbread.
I am following this [link](http://source.android.com/devices/camera/camera.html), but didn't got any useful standard skeleton to write camera HAL.

The Android Camera HAL i want to write is for Raspberry pi board's camera.

Comment: The page you linked to actually points to an example implementation (hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera). But if you expect help with implementating the camera HAL for your hardware you should narrow down the scope of the problem first, so that a specific and reasonably sized answer can be given to the question.

Comment: @michael the camera HAL is for raspberry pi board's camera.

Comment: "How do I write a camera HAL for the raspberry pi?" isn't exactly a narrowly scoped question. If you have trouble getting started, perhaps there are some Android or raspberry pi developer forums where you can get help.

Comment: from a week i am searching regarding same, but didn't got useful info. thanks for suggestion michael.